# .vimrc file not working

Tags: vim

I have the following short and simple .vimrc file that I've started as I begin to learn and write my own .vimrc:

```
  1 set number
  2 
  3 highlight GoComment xtermfg=blue
  4 
  5 syntax on
```

However, when I try to source it, I get the following:

```
Error detected while processing /home/matt/.vimrc:
line    3:
E423: Illegal argument: xtermfg=blue
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

as well as:

```
Command 'highlight' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install highlight
syntax: command not found
```

does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Bear with me, I haven't made my own .vimrc file before

Comment: What do you mean "source it"? You just run `vim`, you don't source anything... if you `source` or `.` it, your shell will try to execute those statements.

Comment: I ran vim as well, I still get the errors

Comment: What are you running? `vim` is never going to tell you to install something with `apt` to my knowledge.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, and I recently installed go and vim-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 3 of your `.vimrc` file [should probably be](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-ctermfg):

`highlight GoComment ctermfg=blue`

[You can only choose](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#highlight-args) between `term` (normal terminal), `cterm` (color terminal, including xterm) and `gui`.

As for your last screen dump (« Command 'highlight' not found ... »), it makes no sense in a vim context. It appears you tried to execute your vimrc file as if it was a shell script.

Comment: the issue was I was using xtermfg instead of ctermfg, thanks!